# How to use term describe `out of scope` job, but it is a company tasks

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing the scope of work(SOW). I divided into 2 parts.

1. in scope
2. out of scope

By nature of startup. I am hired to do on a specific tasks by contract, but in the up front job. I have a chance to do out of scope task as well. This is good for developing my skillsets and I take it as a part of growing up.

**Question:**

What is the best fit in writing instead of using `out of scope` job?
On top of my head is `ad hoc assignments`, but I feels it is wired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may call such jobs ***voluntary***.

ODO:

> **[voluntary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/voluntary)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **2** Working, done, or maintained without payment.
>
> ‘The school cleaner volunteers have been protesting for about a month
>   outside the gates of the legislature, demanding payment for voluntary
>   work offered since 1997.’

Also, the phrase ***pro bono*** is used (typically in the legal profession).

ODO:

> ***[pro bono](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pro_bono)***
>
> *ADVERB & ADJECTIVE* [North American]
>   **Denoting work undertaken without charg**e, especially legal work for a client on low income.
>
> ‘Most of the many hours he works each day are pro bono to help the
>   administration with its policy on Iraq.’

Answer (score 0):

If the work is for the company but not in your official job description, you could say it is **outside my remit**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using SOW to mean 'Scope of Work'.  In all cases in my work experience it has meant 'Statement of Work'.  A document that describes the effort to produce what is wanted.  If it is easier, or safer to include what is not wanted, then I suggest you not look for a single word to replace 'out of scope'.  I suggest that the phrase 'out of scope' is clearly understood, very common, and is the right phrase to help you communicate what you do not want (or at least what you will not provide or pay for).